# How to get the current min and max values of x and y axes in ILNumerics?

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

I'm displaying a simple 2D Line Plot in ILNumerics using a plot cube. I would like to be able to fix and save the current X- and Y-Axis limits after the user zoomed into the graph. Hence, I tried to receive the  upper and lower limits of the axes via:

```
   var xMin = plotCube.Axes.GetLimits().XMin
   var xMax = plotCube.Axes.GetLimits().XMax
```

But these values are wrong (-3.40282347E+38 (xMax) and 3.40282347E+38(xMin)).

How can I retrieve the current max and min values of the axes?
How can I set the limits when creating a new plot cube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set limits:

```
plotCube.Limits.Set(new Vector3(0,0,0), new Vector3(2,2,2));
```

http://ilnumerics.net/apidoc/?topic=html/M_ILNumerics_Drawing_ILLimits_Set.htm

Get limits of all 3 coordinates:

```
Vector3 min = plotCube.Limits.Min, max = plotCube.Limits.Max;
```

http://ilnumerics.net/apidoc/?topic=html/Properties_T_ILNumerics_Drawing_ILLimits.htm